# Incorrect sorting order of NULL values with a SQL view

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I am trying return design an `SQL View` which returns `TOP 3` records from a table in ascending order considering `NULL` values in the table as the largest value so that I can discard the null values from top 3 results if there are more than three records.

I was able to successfully do it using following query but for reasons it is misbehaving w.r.t the third record is that if the third and fourth record in my table are same then my view is returning a NULL value are the third record which is kind of weird.

For Example Consider I have a column in my table named `Grades` with values `23,45,19,35,35`

and when I run my view it should return top 3 values in ascending order which are `19,23,35` but for some reasons my query returns `19,23,NULL`  and the query works fine if my third record that is 35 is distinct ie if the `Grades` are `23,45,19,35,40`  then it works fine and returns `19,23,35`

My Query is as follows

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test]
AS

SELECT distinct

   CC.Grades,
   CC.Term,  
   FROM CanadianCrudes CC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 3  Grades
             FROM CanadianCrudes iCC
             WHERE CC.Term = iCC.Term 
             ORDER BY case 
                       when iCC.Grades is null 
                        then 1 
                        else 0 end, iCC.Grades asc ) iCC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your grades have a limit to how high they can go could you use an isnull in your orderby and set a default high value for null occurences and a tie breaker for when two values have the same rank (e.g 35)

e.g

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test]
AS

SELECT distinct

   CC.Grades,
   CC.Term,  
   FROM CanadianCrudes CC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 3  Grades
             FROM CanadianCrudes iCC
             WHERE CC.Term = iCC.Term 
             ORDER BY isnull(iCC.Grades, 150), ID
```

Comment: how do I use a tie breaker

Comment: Well its just a second item in theorder by clause. I used id in my example so I you have two of the same grade it would move onto the next column in your order by and decide which of the two of them goes highest on the list

Answer (score 1):

**Important Note**

You might have ordered results in a View's Definition but it does not guarantee ordered result when you actually select from view.

In your case it will pick the tops 3 values for each Grade but the order in which results and returned and displayed is not guaranteed, Unless you use Order By in your select statement when selecting from view.

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1), (2),(3),(5),(NULL),(NULL)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM @TABLE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 100000 ELSE ID END ASC
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╗
║  ID  ║
╠══════╣
║ 1    ║
║ 2    ║
║ 3    ║
║ 5    ║
║ NULL ║
║ NULL ║
╚══════╝
```

Comment: The OP wanted the Nulls *last*, not first, and was confused why his code was placing a Null in his top 3 results.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix if an answer is wrong you need to hold your horses and give OPs a chance to correct it, Down voting should be used carefully.

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks and the above case works fine but as in my question when there are two third values then it returns the third value as NULL. In your example 1 2 3 5 NULL NULL works fine but when the values are 1 2 3 3 NULL NULL then my view returns 1 2 NULL provided I just want only the top three values unlike in your answer.

Comment: @M.Ali Even if there is no NULL in my values it still returns a NULL if there are multiple values for number 3 spot and Also I was able to get the same results you got with the query in my question.

Comment: @M.Ali I disagree. Your answer was wrong so I downvoted. So long as I'm willing to monitor the answer and remove the downvote if it's updated to a correct answer, then it's fine. Even then though, the answer was still *wrong*.

Comment: @M.Ali Hmm. Fair point actually I suppose... Assuming you convinced me your answer was right and didn't edit, I could be locked out from removing it.